# Ending the loop within an if statement

Tags: java

I am making a palindrome calculator. Here is my code

```
class test{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String word="";
    String test="";
    int left = 0;
    int leftt = 1;

    while(!word.equals("END")){
        word = BIO.getString();                 
        test = word;
        {
            String wordLC = word.toLowerCase();
            int rightt = wordLC.length()-2;
            int right = wordLC.length()-1;
            {
                if(word == "END"){
                    break;
                }       
                else if(word.charAt(left) == word.charAt(right) && word.charAt(leftt) == word.charAt(rightt)){
                System.out.printf("%-10s is a palindrome",word);

                }else{
                System.out.printf("%-10s is not a palindrome",word);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

}
}

I want to make it that when the word 'END' is put in, everything is shut down. I've tried to do this with the while and the if statement within the while.

The word END does end the loop, however it will carry on to state : "END   is not a palindrome".

where as I just want the loop to end.

Thanks

Comment: `if(word == "END")` read the duplicate to learn how to compare strings in Java.

Comment: Why is the if statement inside of a block?

Comment: idk i just formated it like so, however removed it